# Where in the stack to best merge analytical data-warehouse data with data scraped+cached from third-party APIs?

Tags: caching, data-warehouse, cqrs

##### Background information

We sell an API to users, that analyzes and presents corporate financial-portfolio data derived from public records.

We have an "analytical data warehouse" that contains all the raw data used to calculate the financial portfolios. This data warehouse is fed by an ETL pipeline, and so isn't "owned" by our API server per se. (E.g. the API server only has read-only permissions to the analytical data warehouse; the schema migrations for the data in the data warehouse live alongside the ETL pipeline rather than alongside the API server; etc.)

We also have a small document store (actually a Redis instance with persistence configured) that *is* owned by the API layer. The API layer runs various jobs to write into this store, and then queries data back as needed. You can think of this store as a shared persistent cache of various bits of the API layer's in-memory state. The API layer stores things like API-key blacklists in here.

##### Problem statement

All our input data is denominated in USD, and our calculations occur in USD. However, we give our customers the query-time option to convert the response just-in-time to another currency. We do this by having the API layer run a background job to scrape exchange-rate data, and then cache it in the document store. Individual API-layer nodes then do (in-memory-cached-with-TTL) fetches from this exchange-rates key in the store, whenever a query result needs to be translated into a specific currency.

At first, we thought that this unit conversion wasn't really "about" our data, just about the API's UX, and so we thought this was entirely an API-layer concern, where it made sense to store the exchange-rates data into our document store.

(Also, we noticed that, by not pre-converting our DB results into a specific currency on the DB side, the calculated results of a query for a particular portfolio became more cache-friendly; the way we're doing things, we can cache and reuse the portfolio query results between queries, even if the queries want the results in different currencies.)

But recently we've been expanding into also allowing partner clients to also execute complex data-science/Business Intelligence queries directly against our analytical data warehouse. And it turns out that they will also, often, need to do final exchange-rate conversions in their BI queries as well—despite there being no API layer involved here.

It seems like, to serve the needs of BI querying, the exchange-rate data "should" actually live in the analytical data warehouse alongside the financial data; and the ETL pipeline "should" be responsible for doing the API scraping required to fetch and feed in the exchange-rate data.

But this *feels* wrong: the exchange-rate data has a different lifecycle and integrity constraints than our financial data. The exchange rates are dirty and ephemeral point-in-time samples attained by scraping, whereas the financial data is a reliable historical event stream. The exchange rates get constantly updated/overwritten, while the financial data is append-only. Etc.

What is the best practice for serving the needs of analytical queries that need to access backend "application state" for "query result presentation" needs like this? Or am I wrong in thinking of this exchange-rate data as "application state" in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

What I find interesting about your scenario is about when the exchange rate data is applicable.

In the case of the API, it's all about the realtime value in the other currency and it makes sense to have the most recent value in your API app scope (Redis).

However, I assume your analytical data warehouse has tables with purchases that were made at a certain time. In those cases, the current exchange rate is not really relevant to the value of the transaction.

This might mean that you want to store the exchange rate history in your warehouse or expand the "purchases" table to store the values in all the currencies at that moment.